# Searchable scrolling List with SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, search, android-edittext, simplecursoradapter, autoscroll

I have a `ListView` with a data set of persons in a `SimpleCursorAdapter`. Now I have an `EditText` and I want to scroll the `list` to the matching entry without doing a query for the search term.

I want to always keep all entries in my `list`.

How is this possible?

Comment: see ListView.setSelection

Comment: yes but I need to find out which entry is the right one first, and thats my problem, because I don´t have a list, I have a Cursor

Comment: so you need to iterate over your original Cursor and compare the row ID with the row ID of matching item

Comment: I didn´t thought about that, whyever :D thank you